# Trim domain field by default

Tags: grails, groovy

What is the best way to trim field value in domain?

My suggestion is to use `beforeSave()`, but would work something like this?

```
class Book {

  String name = name?.trim()

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options depending on what behavior you want.

1. A custom setter, which will trim the value every time you set it

   ```
   class Book {
       String name

       void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name?.trim()
       }
   }
   ```
2. A custom getter, which will give you a trimmed value but not store it in the database

   ```
   class Book {
       String name

       String getName() {
           this.@name?.trim()
       }
   }
   ```
3. A hibernate event, like `beforeSave()` as you mentioned, which will only trim it before the object is persisted.

Comment: Thanks, I would like something last like Book.list() with trimmed name, what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: Any one of these will work for that case unless the DB already contains data or is updated by another source. If either of those are the case, you would want option 2.

Comment: Thanks, the second point works for me. Could you explain, how does @name work with criteria and list(), please?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can enable automatic trimming of string in Grails (version 2.3+) by setting below property in `Config.groovy` file:

```
grails.databinding.trimStrings = true
```

This will automatic trim the string before save or update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think, it's a feature of grails 2.3, but I use 2.2

Comment: Oh Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: This will not “automatic trim the string before save or update”.  This is only relevant during data binding.  This setting causes the data binder to trim strings and does not affect the save process.  For example, if you do something like "def foo = new Something(); foo.name='  padded with spaces '; foo.save()", that String value will not be trimmed.  The property name has "databinding" in it on purpose.  The setting only applies to the data binding process.

Answer (score 1):

I have have noticed that Grails automatically does a .trim() on fields before persisting them.  For example:

```
null
""
"      "
```

All gets stored as null in Grails 2.3.7 for a nullable string.  In addition:

```
"      foobar     "
```

gets stored as "foobar"

These results are using the default h2 database.  So you might let Grails do the heavy lifting in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I use grails 2.2, so properties not trimmed by default

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hack for quickly trimming all fields in a domain object. I often receive JSON data that is not formatted in a way that would allow me to use data-binding techniques. This method can be called after updating or assigning all values in the domain instance.

```
class Book {

  def trimFields() {
        this.properties = this.properties
    }

}
```

Requires this configuration which is set by default in Grails

```
grails.databinding.trimStrings = true
```

I know this is overkill but it's quick and easy to add to a domain class.